# python dateutil -different behaviour on Linux vs. Windows

Tags: python, python-dateutil

Why am I getting different results from this code on Windows vs. Linux:

```
In [1]: from dateutil.rrule import rrule, DAILY, MONTHLY, MO, TU, WE, TH, FR

In [2]: from datetime import date, datetime

In [3]: r = rrule(MONTHLY, byweekday=TH(3), bymonth=(3,6,9,12), dtstart=datetime(2009,3,19))

In [4]: r.after(datetime(2015,3,1,12))
Out[4]: datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 5, 0, 0)
```

On windows I get:

```
In [1]: from dateutil.rrule import rrule, DAILY, MONTHLY, MO, TU, WE, TH, FR

In [2]: from datetime import date, datetime

In [3]: r = rrule(MONTHLY, byweekday=TH(3), bymonth=(3,6,9,12), dtstart=datetime(2009,3,19))

In [4]: r.after(datetime(2015,3,1,12))
Out[4]: datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 19, 0, 0)
```

Note that the machines are in different timezones.

Comment: So what's the difference in timezone between the two machines...?

Comment: I think your linux environment has some issues, I get the same results as windows on my ubuntu setup...

Comment: Actually, it lookslike a bug in dateutil as I can recreate the issue on my mac at home... It works ok in dateutil 1.5, but fails (ie the result is datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 5, 0, 0)) in dateutil 2.4

Comment: I've raised an issue on github [link]https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/issues/46

Comment: FYI this issue got fixed https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/issues/34

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the correct `datetime(2015, 3, 19, 0, 0)` on my Linux machine (`dateutil-2.0`).

```
>>> import calendar
>>> calendar.prmonth(2015, 3)
     March 2015
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
                   1
 2  3  4  5  6  7  8
 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20 21 22
23 24 25 26 27 28 29
30 31
```

The local timezone does not matter in this case -- `2015-03-19` may correspond to different UTC times in different timezones but as long as Gregorian calendar is used, `2015-03-05` won't be the 3rd Thursday of the month whatever the local timezone is.

Try to update your `dateutil` version on your Linux machine.